# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration

Tags: java, spring-boot

1. I set up the project myself springboot+dubbo,The project can get up
   normally,but I added a fusing mechanism
   spring-cloud-starter-hystrix,The project won't come up。 Depending on
   the following： 
           org.springframework.boot
           spring-boot-starter-parent
           1.4.7.RELEASE

   ```
   <properties>
       <springboot_version>1.4.7.RELEASE</springboot_version>
       <springboot_dubbo_version>2.0.0</springboot_dubbo_version>
       <netflix_hystrix_version>1.4.4.RELEASE</netflix_hystrix_version>
       <zookeeper_version>3.4.8</zookeeper_version>
       <zkclient_version>0.9</zkclient_version>
       <junit_version>4.12</junit_version>
   </properties>

   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
           <version>${springboot_version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.alibaba.spring.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>dubbo-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
           <version>${springboot_dubbo_version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
           <scope>compile</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
           <version>${springboot_version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>junit</groupId>
           <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
           <version>${junit_version}</version>
           <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
       <!-- zookeeper start-->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
           <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
           <version>${zookeeper_version}</version>
           <scope>compile</scope>
           <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                   <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
           </exclusions>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.101tec</groupId>
           <artifactId>zkclient</artifactId>
           <version>${zkclient_version}</version>
           <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                   <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
           </exclusions>
       </dependency>
       <!-- zookeeper end-->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.bee.tsmall</groupId>
           <artifactId>tsmall-common</artifactId>
           <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
       </dependency>
       <!--<dependency>-->
       <!--<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>-->
       <!--<artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>-->
       <!--<version>${netflix_hystrix_version}</version>-->
       <!--<exclusions>-->
       <!--<exclusion>-->
       <!--<groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>-->
       <!--<artifactId>guava</artifactId>-->
       <!--</exclusion>-->
       <!--<exclusion>-->
       <!--<groupId>com.netflix.archaius</groupId>-->
       <!--<artifactId>archaius-core</artifactId>-->
       <!--</exclusion>-->
       <!--</exclusions>-->
       <!--</dependency>-->
       <dependency> <!--I add this dependence to the mistake -->
           <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
           <version>1.4.5.RELEASE</version>
           <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                   <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>com.netflix.archaius</groupId>
                   <artifactId>archaius-core</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
           </exclusions>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   ```

**Error**

> The error is as follows：**strong text** 09:56:57.825 [main] ERROR
>       org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup
>       failed java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class
>       [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration]
>         at
>       org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:287)
>         at
>       org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:176)
>         at
>       org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:102)
>         at
>       org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:68)
>         at
>       org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
>         at
>       org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
>         at
>       org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)
>         at
>       org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:72)
>         at
>       org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
>         at
>       org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:338)
>         at
>       org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:309)
>         at
>       org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1187)
>         at
>       org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1176)
>         at
>       com.bee.tsmall.ProducerApplication.main(ProducerApplication.java:24)
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>       org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)   at
>       java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>       sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)     at
>       java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>       org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:250)  at
>       org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:284)
>         ... 13 common frames omitted

Look forward to your answer。

Comment: show the code of your main configuration class & try to bind @enableautoconfiguration

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48319717/cannot-find-class-org-springframework-boot-autoconfigure-context-propertyplaceho ?