# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to run a basic SpringBoot application. I am providing here main class code-

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class ConfigServerApplication {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ConfigServerApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

my pom file is-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.pluralsight.configserver</groupId>
<artifactId>config_server</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>config_server</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <!-- <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.M3</spring-cloud.version> -->
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Edgware.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

When I run the code the error in console is-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration]
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:287)
at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:176)
at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:102)
at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:68)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:166)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:121)
at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:111)
at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:65)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:330)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
at com.pluralsight.configserver.ConfigServerApplication.main(ConfigServerApplication.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:250)
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:284)
... 14 more
```

I tried using dependency for **autoconfigure** in `pom.xml`, also tried `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, the code isn't working.

Any help to resolve this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your dependency doesn't seems fully resolved... you should check your classpath...

Comment: Follow this contribution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48319717/cannot-find-class-org-springframework-boot-autoconfigure-context-propertyplaceho