# Boot application fails to start when adding config cloud client dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I have a Spring Boot 1.4.1 application which works just fine. I have set up a separate application as the config server using Spring Cloud Config Server which is based on boot 2.2.1.RELEASE.
Now I am trying to use this config server in my boot 1.4.1 application for which I am adding the following gradle dependency-

compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config:1.4.1.RELEASE')

As I add this my application, it fails to start complaining this-

```
    Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoC
onfiguration]
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:287)
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:176
)
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:102)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader.loadClass(RestartClassLoader.java:151)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:250)
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:284)
```

Any ideas what could be going wrong here?

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/49662845/1069633

Comment: Saw that. It is not exactly the same, I suspect my autoconfigure dependency is getting messed up somehow after adding the cloud config starter dependency.